# Control the tables generated by SimpleMembershipProvider?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, webmatrix, simplemembership

I found `SimpleMembershipProvider` to be pretty neat and productive.

I was wondering if there is a way to control the generate table/column names/datatypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the table name for the user table and the column names for the user id and user name columns in it. You specify those in the InitializeDatabaseConnection method. The SimpleMembershipProvider expects the UserId column to be an IDENTITY column. It uses @@IDENTITY to obtain the ID of newly created records. Currently, the SimpleMembershipProvider only works with SQL Server (Express or Full) or SQL Compact 4.0 databases.

You can't change the schema of the membership or roles tables. The SQL for managing accounts and using those tables is hard-coded into the SimpleMemberhipProvider.